# How small should an area be before a question is considered too localized?

Tags: discussion

Or do we count how many countries are involved? Because if we do consider area, I think it's rather discriminatory. Countries like Canada or India for example, have large areas. I'm referring to one of the reasons for voting to close a thread btw:

> This question is unlikely to help any future visitors; it is only
>   relevant to a **small geographic area**, a specific moment in time, or an
>   extraordinarily narrow situation that is not generally applicable to
>   the worldwide audience of the internet. For help making this question
>   more broadly applicable, see the FAQ.

Comment: The community uses its judgment. IMHO, it tends to be generous, allowing even questions about large cities stand.  The ones that are closed are usually clearly of very limited interest.

Comment: I think that quote is hardwired into the Stackexchange app.  Before closing a question I think we always provide a more detailed justification in the comments section.  Is this not the case?

Comment: Got it. Thanks for your responses :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it concerns a close reason choice that is no longer offered.